# How can I back .htaccess on my wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Unfortunately I deleted .htaccess page from my wordpress. Now if I click on any post or category it show page could not found. What should I do now? How can I solve it?
Any body have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I would start by creating a temporary `.htaccess` following the default WordPress model available at their website which looks like this:](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks)

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Then you will need to check the pages and everything to see what is still not working and fix it.

If your blog is on a different folder or configured differently the above may need to be changed depending on that.

For example folder structure, etc.